# Assign variable name based on the assigned feature class

Tags: python

I want to use intersect as a variable name to save the feature class (C:\intersect.shp) and use point as a variable name to save the another one (C:\point.shp), which means the variable names should be based on the file names. I can use os.path.split(fc)[1][:-4] to select out the part I want, but how to use it as a variable in arcpy?

To be more specific, I want the variable_name in the following code can be changed accordingly to the fc name.

```
def variable(fc):
    variable_name = os.path.split(fc)[1][:-4]
    return variable_name
```

Comment: As indicated by [@Midavalo](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226424/115) this is pure Python rather than ArcPy and so is better researched at [so].

Answer (score 2):

This is more just raw python rather than arcpy, but you just need to create a new variable and take the returned data as the value for that new variable.

In my example below I pass my `pointFC` name to your `variable()` function, and it will return the value, into the `myNewPointVar` variable, that is then passed to `arcpy.Describe()`

```
import arcpy

def variable(fc):
    variable_name = os.path.split(fc)[1][:-4]
    return variable_name

pointfc = r"C:\point.shp"    
myNewPointVar = variable(pointfc)

desc = arcpy.Describe(myNewPointVar)
```